# PHP unlink (delele ) multiple files on server

Tags: php, file, path, filepath, unlink

Sometimes, I have to delete multiple files in different folders on the server. It's a tedious job to to this one by one via FTP. I wrote a little script that does the job. I can import the list of files in Excel and copy and paste them in the script. However, my approach is not elegant:

```
$file1 = "some-file.php";
$file12 = "some-file2.php";

...

if (!empty($file1)) {
if ( @unlink ( $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/".$file1 ) )
{
  echo 'The file <strong><span style="color:green;">' . $file1 . '</span></strong> was deleted!<br />';
}
else
{
  echo 'Couldn't delete the file <strong><span style="color:red;">' . $file1 . '</span></strong>!<br />';
}}
if (!empty($file2)) { ...
```

I would rather like to do this with a foreach and an array, but don't know how. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: RTFM, then: [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put your files into an array and loop it.

```
$files = array('some-file.php', 'some-file2.php');

foreach ($files as $file) {
  if ( @unlink ( $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/".$file ) ) {
    echo 'The file <strong><span style="color:green;">' . $file . '</span></strong> was deleted!<br />';
  } else {
    echo 'Couldn\'t delete the file <strong><span style="color:red;">' . $file . '</span></strong>!<br />';
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any other way rather than foreach?? like we pass an array of paths and that all files will be deleted at a time

Answer (score 0):

also, i think its better if you use file_exists()

```
if (file_exists($file1)) 
{
unlink ( $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/".$file1 );
clearstatcache();
}
```

Comment: why? what happens if you unlink a file that does no exist?

Comment: @njzk2 it's just a precaution, if file is locked or otherwise not accessible at that time. file_eixsts() will throw an error - that's why i remove the @ at the start of the unlink also.

Comment: If file does not exist, it will silently return `false`, no need `file_exists`.